# How to generalize utility function using method references/java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I've run into a common situation where i have a list of objects and need to generate a comma separated string with a single property, which are then each surrounded by single quotes.

2 Examples

```
public String partIDsToString(List<Part> parts){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Part part : parts)
        sb.append("'"+part.getPartNumber() + "',");
    return sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);
}

public String companyIDsToString(List<Company> parts){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Company c : parts)
        sb.append("'"+c.getId() + "',");
    return sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);
}
```

I'll need to create more methods like this in the future, and was wondering if there was a way to generalize this functionality, im looking for something like this.

```
public String objectPropertyToString(List<Object> list, Method getProperty){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Object obj: list)
        sb.append("'"+obj.getProperty() + "',");
    return sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);
}

List<Company> companies = getCompaniesList();//not important
String result = objectPropertyToString(companies , Company::getId);

List<Part> parts= getPartsList();//not important
String result = objectPropertyToString(parts, Part::getPartNumber);
```

Can this be done using method references/lambdas, or any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Stream.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) are your friends here.

```
companies.stream()
         .map(Company::getId)
         .map(s -> "'" + s + "'")
         .collect(joining(","));
```

You can create a helper method, but in my judgement the above is succinct enough that it isn't worthwhile:

```
static <T> String mapAndJoin(Collection<T> c, Function<T,String> f){
    return c.stream()
            .map(f)
            .map(s -> "'" + s + "'")
            .collect(joining(","));
}

mapAndJoin(companies, Company::getId);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36636973/2711488), `Collectors.joining` can be used to produce a comma separator list. But you can also use it to enclose the elements in single quotes in one go, which is more efficient than doing this in a separate String operation per element before joining them.

The basic idea is as follows:

```
public static <T> String objectPropertyToString(
                  Collection<? extends T> list, Function<T,String> f) {
    return list.stream().map(f).collect(Collectors.joining("', '", "'", "'"));
}
```

Instead of just separating the elements with just a comma, we separate with a closing single quote, followed by comma and an opening single quote. Further, we use an opening single quote as starter before the first element and a closing single quote after the last element.

This works smoothly, with only one exception: if the list is empty, we get a sole `''` as result because the initial opening quote and trailing closing quote is always produced. To solve this, we have to retrace what `Collectors.joining` does internally, to get hands on the `StringJoiner` used for the process, so we can configure it in a way not offered by the built-in collector:

```
public static <T> String objectPropertyToString(
                  Collection<? extends T> list, Function<T,? extends CharSequence> f) {
    return list.stream().map(f).collect(
        ()->new StringJoiner("', '", "'", "'").setEmptyValue(""),
        StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge).toString();
}
```

This basically does the same as the previous attempt with the notable exception that we now can use `setEmptyValue` to specify the different result for the case that there were no elements. As a bonus we can now relax the generic type signature, allowing arbitrary `CharSequence` instances to be joined instead of just `String`s.

The usage is as before:

```
List<Company> companies = getCompaniesList();//not important
String result = objectPropertyToString(companies , Company::getId);

List<Part> parts= getPartsList();//not important
String result = objectPropertyToString(parts, Part::getPartNumber);
```