# Avoid prefix suffix for blank string in Collectors.joining

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement to read the string from a list and join them with ','. Also need to add comma in prefix and suffix of the total output string.
Example : If list contans["a","b","c"] then output would be ",a,b,c,".

Now thats perfectly working with Collectors.joining but if the list does not contains any value then also in output strting I am getting ",," as output because prefix and suffix is added.

Now what I want is to avoid the prefix and suffix in case if blank String. So, any suggestion?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", ",", ","));
        System.out.println(result);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")` or `String.join(",",list);`

Comment: Cannot answer as this has been marked as a duplicate, but `.collect(() -> new StringJoiner(",", ",", ",").setEmptyValue(""), StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge).toString()` should work.

Comment: @Bubletan since this kind of solution is already in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36642371/2711488), I added the particular Q&A to the list of duplicates…

Comment: I do not think the two listed questions answer this question. But [this later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56560952/859640) does.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the list has elements:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String result = "";
if (!list.isEmpty())
{
  result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",",",",","));
}
System.out.println(result);
```