# Custom Collector to join stream on delimiter, suffix and prefix only if stream is not empty suffix

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a stream of strings:

`Stream<String> stream = ...;`

I want to create a string using

`stream.collect(Collectors.joining(',', '[', ']'))`

only I want to return "No Strings" if the stream does not contain any elements.

I notice that `String java.util.stream.Stream.collect(Collector<? super String, ?, String> collector)`
method takes an argument of type java.util.stream.Collector<T, A, R>

For my project I need to this functionality in many places so I would need a class the implements the `Collector` interface.

I know this could be done by Stream to a List and then checking on List.size() == 0? and then convert the list to a stream again if needed.

```
List<String> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

if (list.size() == 0) {
    return "No Strings";
}
return list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));`
```

## This is what I would like to happen

`List emptyList<String> = new ArrayList<>; System.out.println(emptyList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")));`

### Output

`[]`

### Output I would like

`No Strings`

Comment: Well, how about starting by creating a collector and showing your effort so far? This even would be nicely unit-testable!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honestly, I would go with your current approach (testing for emptiness).

But if you really wanted to use a straight collector, you could use [the source code of `Collections.joining`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l295) and [the Javadoc of `StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html#setEmptyValue-java.lang.CharSequence-) as a guide to make a custom collector:

```
Collector.of(
    () -> new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]").setEmptyValue("No strings"),
    StringJoiner::add,
    StringJoiner::merge,
    StringJoiner::toString)
```

Comment: Perfect, thats what I was looking for

Comment: There is no need to create a custom Collector. You can pass it directly to [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and use `toString()` at the end: `stream.collect(() -> new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]").setEmptyValue("No Strings"), StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge).toString();`

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp correct for this use case or [similar use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46101849/2711488), but creating a `Collector` allows combining with other collectors, like `groupingBy`. The best choice would be creating a factory method similar to the methods in `Collectors`, i.e. a `joining` with four parameters. Then, it can be used or combined like all others.